# Undefined variable while inseting values into the table

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying insert the values to the table created
but when I do that it gives me an error saying undefined variable
but I have declared it in the main function and values have been assigned to those variables

Here is my code.
    #!/usr/bin/python3

```
import requests
import sqlite3
def get_info(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    page = response.json()
    name = page['name']
    category = page['category']
    link = page['link']
    location = page['location']['city']
    likes = page['likes']
    checkins = page['checkins']
    return name,category,link,location,likes,checkins

def main():
    link = 'https://graph.facebook.com/Indiatoday'
    p_name,p_cat,p_link,p_loc,p_likes,p_check = get_info(link)
    print ('the page details are '+p_name,p_cat,p_link,p_loc,p_likes,p_check)

db = sqlite3.connect('page.db')
db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS page_info (
           id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
           name TEXT,
           category TEXT,
           link TEXT,
           location TEXT,
           likes INTEGER,
           checking INTEGER)''')
print ('table created successfully')
db.execute('''INSERT INTO page_info (name, category, link, location, likes,Checking) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)''',(p_name,p_cat,p_link,p_loc,p_likes,p_check))
db.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Am getting the error message "NameError: name 'p_name' is not defined"
it would be helpful if anyone could be let me know what I am doing wrong here. I know its a simple variable defining but I couldnt find it

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
db.execute('''INSERT INTO page_info (name, category, link, location, likes,Checking) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)''',(p_name,p_cat,p_link,p_loc,p_likes,p_check))
```

is executed before any of these variables have been declared (since it's not indented and therefore not part of `main()`). I think you need to indent the entire block:

```
def main():
    link = 'https://graph.facebook.com/Indiatoday'
    p_name,p_cat,p_link,p_loc,p_likes,p_check = get_info(link)
    print ('the page details are '+p_name,p_cat,p_link,p_loc,p_likes,p_check)

    db = sqlite3.connect('page.db')
    db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS page_info (
               id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
               name TEXT,
               category TEXT,
               link TEXT,
               location TEXT,
               likes INTEGER,
               checking INTEGER)''')
    print ('table created successfully')
    db.execute('''INSERT INTO page_info (name, category, link, location, likes,Checking) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)''',(p_name,p_cat,p_link,p_loc,p_likes,p_check))
    db.commit()
```

Comment: It worked! But still when inserting values it gives me a error message as 'sqlite3.OperationalError: table page_info has no column named name' . Is there something wrong with the insert command?

Comment: I don't know - it seems the table should be having that column. I haven't worked with sqlite3 yet, so I'm not really qualified to say.